# Getting count of current used file descriptors from C code

Tags: c, linux

Is there a C API to get the:

1. Current used file descriptors system wide
2. Current used file descriptors of the current process

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For the current process count, you can use `getrlimit` to get the file descriptor limit, then iterate over all integers from 0 to that limit and try calling `fcntl` with the `F_GETFD` command. It will succeed only on the file descriptors which are actually open, letting you count them.

**Edit:** I now have a better way to do it. After getting the `rlimit`, make a large array of `struct pollfd` (as large as the limit if possible; otherwise you can break it down into multiple runs/calls) with each fd in the range and the `events` member set to 0. Call `poll` on the array with 0 timeout, and look for the `POLLNVAL` flag in the `revents` for each member. This will tell you which among a potentially-huge set of fds are invalid with a single syscall, rather than one syscall per fd.

Answer (score 15):

Since you say you are on Linux, you can open the folder `/proc/self/fd/` which should contain symbolic links to all open *file descriptors*.

Answer (score 13):

You can read `/proc/sys/fs/file-nr` to find the total number of allocated and free file system handles as well as the maximum allowed.

```
[root@box proc]# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
3853    908     53182
|       |       |
|       |       |
|       |       max: maximum open file descriptors
|       free: total free allocated file descriptors
allocated: total allocated file descriptors since boot
```

To calculate the number that are currently in use, just do `allocated - free`. You could also calculate a percentage of used descriptors by doing `((allocated - free) / max) * 100`

As for per-process, I'm not sure of any programmatic way you can do it.

Here's a tutorial on how to do it with `lsof` anyway: http://linuxshellaccount.blogspot.com/2008/06/finding-number-of-open-file-descriptors.html

Comment: I believe these are actually counts of open file descriptions, not file descriptors, i.e. the value is unaffected by `dup` or `fork`.

Comment: `allocated` tells you the number allocated since boot, `free` tells you the number of those that have been freed. `allocated - free` = the number that are currently open on the system. If you just want to know how many file descriptors have been allocated on the system, just look at `allocated`. Or am I thinking of something different?

Comment: File descriptors and open file descriptions are subtly different. Each open file description can have many file descriptors referring to it (created by `dup`, `dup2`, `fcntl/F_DUPFD`, or inheritance across `fork`) all of which share properties like the current offset in the file, flags like append mode, etc., and the open file description is not closed until *all* file descriptors referring to it are closed.

Comment: @Polynomial 
on my  system  I get following o/p 
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
8064 0 297986
Does it mean I have 8064 used file descriptor

Comment: @R.. - Should a file descriptor that is being referred to "somewhere" not still count as open? I'm not familiar with the internals of it, but my definition of "open" (as a developer that mainly works with GC-based languages) is that something is actively referring to it.

Comment: @VivekGoel - As R.. pointed out, it means that 8064 open file **descriptions** are open. There may be multiple file **descriptors** open for those **descriptions**. Note the difference between descriptions and descriptors. It's a subtle difference, but it's important.

Answer (score 2):

To complement on [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7976828/2427955)'s answer, the most efficient (both in terms of space and time) way of getting the number of open fds for the current process is to walk `/proc/self/fds` where available.

This should do it:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int count_open_fds(void) {
    DIR *dp = opendir("/proc/self/fd");
    struct dirent *de;
    int count = -3; // '.', '..', dp

    if (dp == NULL)
        return -1;

    while ((de = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
        count++;

    (void)closedir(dp);

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not positive about file *descriptors*, but you can easily check `<stdio.h>` files.

In `stdio.h`, `__sF`, is a file array that stores every `FILE`. ([googling `__sF`](https://www.google.com/search?q=extern%20FILE%20__sF) shows many `stdio`s with a matching keyword).

If a `FILE`'s flags are empty, the file is not in use. Therefore, we can simply walk through `__sF`, checking the flag of each `FILE` in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getOpenFileCount(void)
{
    int fileCount;

    for (fileCount = 0; __sF[fileCount]._flags != 0; fileCount++)
        continue;

    return fileCount;
}
```

Comment: Tried your code, got `error: ‘__sF’ undeclared (first use in this function)`.

Comment: @EliezerMiron That's because it's a non-standard BSD extension, as evidenced by the double-underscore.